# Custom params not saving with Stripe account, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

This is my first time working with an API and I am trying to create a managed account with Stripe Connect. I have no problem with creating the account, however I can't seem to get the params from the form to be sent to Stripe on create.

**stripe/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@payment) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  <%= f.select :country, options_for_select(country_select)%>
  <%= f.text_field :month %>
  <%= f.text_field :day %>
  <%= f.text_field :year %>
  <%= f.submit "create merchant account" %>
<% end %>
```

**stripe_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @artist = current_artist

  Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
  @account = Stripe::Account.create(
    managed: true,
    country: params[:country],
    email: @artist.email,
    tos_acceptance: {
      ip: request.remote_ip,
      date: Time.now.to_i
    },
    legal_entity: {
      dob: {
        day: params[:day],
        month: params[:month],
        year: params[:year]
      },
      first_name: params[:first_name],
      last_name: params[:last_name],
      type: 'individual',
    }
  )

  if @account.save
    @payment = @artist.create_artist_payment_setting(
        currency: @account.default_currency,
        country: @account.country,
        stripe_id: @account.id,
        stripe_secret_key: @account.keys.secret,
        stripe_publishable_key: @account.keys.publishable
      )
  end

  redirect_to artist_path(@artist)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `params`, all attributes are nested within a hash `payment`

So try accessing like this:

`params[:payment][:day]` instead of `params[:day]`

`params[:payment][:month]` instead of `params[:month]`

`params[:payment][:year]` instead of `params[:year]`

... so on for all other attributes of your form.